# R: How to avoid 2 'for' loops in R in this function

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

I know there are many topics on how to avoid R loops, but I was not able to understand how I could vectorize my iterations.
I have a data set which here I represent by m. I want to generate a new matrix with this function, that will be composed by the p.values of the correlation coefficients of each column of the data (m).

```
m<-matrix(rnorm(100),nrow=10,ncol=10)
sig.p<-function(x){
  n= ncol(x)
  p.values<-numeric(n)
  p.values<-matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n)
  for (i in 1:C){
    for (t in 1:C){
      p.values[t,i]<-cor.test(x[,i],x[,t])$p.value
    }
  }
  p.values
}
sig.p(m)
```

I was not able to understand how I could use mapply (if that's the case).
Could anyone help with suggestions of how I could vectorize these iterations (with mapply or other)
Thanks in advance!

Cesar

Comment: The matrix `m` that your code defines only has 1 column. Was it supposed to be `matrix(rnorm(100),nrow=10,ncol=10)`?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. matrix(rnorm(100),nrow=10,ncol=10)

Comment: You may be interested to profile some of the answers using `system.time` to see if vectorizing makes the code perform better.

Comment: @akrun you got right. I am looking for a vectorized solution. But, as I am also doing it as an exercise (I'm sort of new to R) to familiarize myself to the properties of some functions (like vectorize, which I did not know) I'm giving myself the work to repeat it a few times. Thanks again!

Comment: @Drizzt I tried a benchmark on `100*100`.  In that one, `rcorr` is the best.  If you can show the timings on bigger dataset, that will be great.

Comment: @akrun you are right. rcorr does it faster. Nice! Thanks

Comment: @Drizzt I updated the post with benchmarks.  The `corr.test` from `psych` is not `fast`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `rcorr` from `library(Hmisc)`

```
 library(Hmisc)
 rcorr(m)$P
```

Or use

```
 library(psych)
 corr.test(as.data.frame(m))$p
```

Or using `outer` from `base R`

```
  outer(1:ncol(m),1:ncol(m), FUN= Vectorize(function(x,y) 
                              cor.test(m[,x], m[,y])$p.value))
```

#### Benchmarks

I tried on a smaller dataset (`100*100`) and a slightly bigger dataset (`1e3*1e3`).  Here are the functions:

```
 akrun <- function() {outer(1:ncol(m1),1:ncol(m1), 
            FUN= Vectorize(function(x,y) cor.test(m1[,x],
                              m1[,y])$p.value))}

 akrun2 <- function(){rcorr(m1)$P}
 agstudy <- function() {M <- expand.grid(seq_len(ncol(m1)),
                          seq_len(ncol(m1)))
      mapply(function(x,y)cor.test(m1[,x], m1[,y])$p.value,M$Var1,M$Var2)}
 vpipk <-function(){
        n <- ncol(m1)
        p.values<-matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n)
   for (i in 1:(n-1)){
      for (t in (i+1):n){
          p.values[t,i]<-cor.test(m1[,i],m1[,t])$p.value
     }
   }
   p.values
  }


 nrussell <- function(){
   sapply(1:ncol(m1), function(z){
   sapply(1:ncol(m1), function(x,Y=z){
     cor.test(m1[,Y],m1[,x])$p.value
     })
   })
}
```

On a `100*100` dataset

```
 library(microbenchmark)
 set.seed(25)
 m1 <- matrix(rnorm(1e2*1e2),nrow=1e2,ncol=1e2)
 microbenchmark(akrun(), akrun2(), agstudy(), vpipk(),
                    nrussell(), unit='relative', times=10L)
 #Unit: relative
 #  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 #   akrun() 257.2310 255.9766 252.2163 254.4946 248.9807 246.5429    10   c
 #  akrun2()   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000    10   a  
 # agstudy() 255.5920 258.0813 253.5411 256.0581 250.4833 249.0503    10   c
 #   vpipk() 125.8218 126.3337 125.4592 126.8479 124.9835 124.1383    10   b 
 #nrussell() 257.9283 256.8480 252.5297 256.0160 250.8853 242.0896    10   c
```

If I change `1e2` to `1e3` (didn't get time to do `microbenchmark`, but here are the `system.time`

```
system.time(akrun())
 # user  system elapsed 
#403.563   0.751 404.198 

system.time(akrun2())
 #  user  system elapsed 
 # 3.110   0.008   3.117 

system.time(agstudy())
 #  user  system elapsed 
 #445.108   0.877 445.947 

system.time(vpipk())
#  user  system elapsed 
#155.597   0.224 155.760 

system.time(nrussell())
#  user  system elapsed 
#452.524   1.220 453.713
```

Comment: Interesting pattern using outer and Vectorize.

Comment: akrun, thank you very much. that's kinda what I was looking. Will compare it to vpipkt's since I want to use the same logic for a 10k iteration

Answer (score 4):

Not nearly as succinct as @akrun's answer, but here's a base R solution:

```
sig.p <- function(M){
  sapply(1:ncol(M), function(z){
    sapply(1:ncol(M), function(x,Y=z){
      cor.test(M[,Y],M[,x])$p.value
    })
  })
}
##
R> sig.p(m)
            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]       [,4]      [,5]       [,6]      [,7]       [,8]        [,9]      [,10]
 [1,] 0.00000000 0.08034470 0.244411381 0.03293644 0.3234899 0.80352003 0.5326317 0.03896285 0.702987267 0.57721440
 [2,] 0.08034470 0.00000000 0.087168145 0.44828479 0.4824117 0.76469973 0.8222813 0.17662866 0.607145382 0.41460977
 [3,] 0.24441138 0.08716815 0.000000000 0.20634394 0.9504582 0.11864029 0.2148186 0.28450468 0.009396629 0.51450066
 [4,] 0.03293644 0.44828479 0.206343943 0.00000000 0.8378530 0.78122849 0.0544312 0.22943728 0.524608029 0.66329385
 [5,] 0.32348990 0.48241166 0.950458153 0.83785303 0.0000000 0.66105999 0.3157296 0.35715193 0.927945195 0.63163949
 [6,] 0.80352003 0.76469973 0.118640294 0.78122849 0.6610600 0.00000000 0.7181462 0.67602651 0.749641726 0.03218081
 [7,] 0.53263166 0.82228134 0.214818607 0.05443120 0.3157296 0.71814620 0.0000000 0.39393423 0.266039043 0.38619000
 [8,] 0.03896285 0.17662866 0.284504679 0.22943728 0.3571519 0.67602651 0.3939342 0.00000000 0.512083873 0.30980598
 [9,] 0.70298727 0.60714538 0.009396629 0.52460803 0.9279452 0.74964173 0.2660390 0.51208387 0.000000000 0.92533524
[10,] 0.57721440 0.41460977 0.514500658 0.66329385 0.6316395 0.03218081 0.3861900 0.30980598 0.925335242 0.00000000
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a typical use of  `mapply`:

```
M <- expand.grid(seq_len(ncol(m),seq_len(ncol(m)))
mapply(function(x,y)cor.test(m[,x], m[,y])$p.value,M$Var1,M$Var2)
```

Comment: are the objects in the `seq_len()` the ncol(m)?

Comment: I tried to do the `mapply` the way you put it, but it returns me a vector of length M full of zeros. It is getting only the diagonal (x=y).

Answer (score 1):

Vectorizing is not always all it is cracked up to be. Not sure how large your actual matrix is, but for this size or even 100 x 100 it is a reasonably small one-time cost.

You can more than double performance by modifying your loop structure as follows:

```
sig.p<-function(x){
    n <- ncol(x)
    p.values<-matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n)
    for (i in 1:(n-1)){
        for (t in (i+1):n){
            p.values[t,i]<-cor.test(x[,i],x[,t])$p.value
        }
    }
    p.values
}
```

Basically only compute the lower triangle, since you know the diagonal will be zero's and the matrix is symmetric.  `mapply` or `sapply` applied over the whole matrix may not perform better than this.

Comment: Also note I eliminated the use of `C` in the loop bounds.

Comment: vpipkt, I will use the same principle to apply late on to a 10000 long iteration I will compare the time of this one with the last one akrun gave, since both seem to be neat. Thank you very much!

Comment: hey this way of yours was just super useful for another operation I needed and was not based on a corr matrix. If you apply this to a graph adjacency matrix, the graph gets symmetric by itself. That's awesome! Thanks again!